# Observe finishing of json loading

Tags: ios, json, swift, properties, httprequest

I have a small question. I want to have a function like this:

```
func performGetRequest(targetURL: NSURL!, completion: (data: NSData?, HTTPStatusCode: Int, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: targetURL)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    let sessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            completion(data: data, HTTPStatusCode: (response as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode, error: error)
        })
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

I found on [appcoda.com](https://www.appcoda.com/youtube-api-ios-tutorial/) but with the option to do something when the data is loaded an finished parsing. Something like:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in

        }, completion: {finished in
            self.functionXY()
    })
```

My full plan is to load json data from two specific pages, the second json link is generated out of the data from the first json. So I what to start a http request after the first one is finished.
When the second is finished I want to call a function that change the my View from loadscreen to mainView.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call the animation code within the completion handler of `performGetRequest:`

```
func aFunction() {
    performGetRequest(yourURL) { (data, HTTPStatusCode, error) in
        if error == nil {
            self.animate()
        }
    }
}

func animate() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in

    }, completion: {finished in
        self.functionXY()
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of simple request you can rely on *Alamofire* or another http/post-request open source libraries. 
Otherwise, you can use *NSURLSessionDataTask* / *NSURLSessionDownloadTask* with corresponding completion handlers

 Hope this may help